# объявление матрицы

Tags: c++, c

Почему нельзя так объявить матрицу?

```
const int** A = new int* [n];
int** A = new const int* [n];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально - вы просто теряете квалификаторы `const` при неявном преобразовании. Если разрешить такие преобразования неявно - можно получить массу неприятностей, например, без проблем изменять константные переменные. Поэтому компилятору надо явно сказать, что вы понимаете, что делаете, и берете ответственность на себя - с использованием `const_cast`:

```
const int** A = const_cast<const int**>(new int* [n]);
int** B = const_cast<int**>(new const int* [n]);
```

И еще - это не *объявление*, каковое на самом деле только

```
const int** A;
int** B;
```

Это вы уже инициализируете объявленные переменные.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть некоторый тип `T`, то вы можете присваивать указатель типа `T *`  указателю типа `const T *`. Например

```
int i = 10;
int *p = &i;
const int *cp = p;
```

То есть когда тип `T` в обоих случаях **одинаков, но отличаются лишь квалификатором** для типа `T`. В этом случае применяется неявное преобразование к указателям.

Еще раз. Обратите внимание, что тип `T`, на которые указывают указатели, один и тот же. Только к типу, на который указывает левый указатель, добавляется квалификатор `const`.

Теперь рассмотрим данное объявление

```
const int** A = new int* [n];
```

В левой части этого объявления имеем указатель который указывает на объект с типом `const int *`. Вы можете упростить это выражение, используя `typedef` объявление.

Например,

```
typedef const int * T;
```

или

```
using T = const int *;
```

Тогда вы можете переписать предложение как

```
T * A = new int* [n];
```

А какой тип имеет объект, на который указывает указатель в правой части от знака присваивания?

Если мы снова введем объявление `typedef`, то получим

```
typedef int * T1;
```

или

```
using T1 = int *;
```

В итоге будем иметь

```
T *a = T1 *tmp;
```

Типы `T` и `T1` - это разные типы, поэтому нет неявного преобразования указателя из одного типа в другой тип. Базовые типы этих указателей отличаются. В одном случае базовый пит - это const int *, а в другом случае - это `int *`.

Вы могли бы записать следующим образом ваше исходное объявление

```
int * const * A = new int* [n];
```

и тогда бы оно у вас компилировалось успешно. Действительно в левой и правой части имеются указатели на тип `int *`. Оба указателя имеют **одинаковый базовый тип объекта**, на который они указывают. Только в левой части добавлен квалификатор `const` к этому типу объекта, как это было описано в самом начале моего ответа.

То есть если вы введете typedef объявление

```
typedef int * T;
```

или

```
using T = int *;
```

то вы можете записать

```
const T * A = new int* [n];
```

Только в этом случае является константным сам указатель на `int`, то есть `int * const`, а не тип объекта на который указывает указатель, как в случае объявления `const int *`.

Аналогичная проблема имеет место и для второго вашего объявления.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование типов забыл:

```
  const int** A1 = (const int**) new int* [10];
  int** A2 = (int**) new const int* [10];
```